# What is causing Local variable referenced before assignment Error?

Tags: python, local-variables

I'm currently working through the MIT Problem Set 2 and I encountered an error that I've fixed, but don't understand why it occurred. The relevant portion of this code is the variable alphabet. I reference it in both functions `is_word_guessed` and `get_guessed_word`. However, when I ran the code, I received the Local variable referenced before assignment error within the `get_guessed_word` function. However, I assigned the variable outside of both functions. On top of that, the function `is_word_guessed` does not produce any errors.

I'm able to fix the error by assigning the alphabet within the function itself, but I'd like to understand the cause of the error so I can learn.

1. Both functions reference the variable alphabet (assigned outside the function), but the only `get_guessed_word` tries to modify the value.
2. I can assume that the error stems from the modification of the variable. But then why doesn't this error appear when I modify secret_word within the same code? (Is it because secret_word is an assigned parameter?)

```
secret_word = 'apple'
letters_guessed = ['a','p','q']#['e', 'i', 'k', 'p', 'r', 's']
alphabet='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'


def is_word_guessed(secret_word, letters_guessed):
    '''
    secret_word: string, the word the user is guessing; assumes all letters are
      lowercase
    letters_guessed: list (of letters), which letters have been guessed so far;
      assumes that all letters are lowercase
    returns: boolean, True if all the letters of secret_word are in letters_guessed;
      False otherwise
    '''
    secret_letters=set()
    for l in secret_word:
        if l in alphabet:
            secret_letters.add(l)
            print('Secret letters are ',secret_letters)
        else:
            pass
    for l in letters_guessed:
        if l in secret_letters:
            secret_letters.remove(l)
            print('Secret letters minus guessed letters are', secret_letters)
        else:
            pass
    if len(secret_letters)==0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
        
print(is_word_guessed(secret_word, letters_guessed))

def get_guessed_word(secret_word, letters_guessed):
    '''
    secret_word: string, the word the user is guessing
    letters_guessed: list (of letters), which letters have been guessed so far
    returns: string, comprised of letters, underscores (_), and spaces that represents
      which letters in secret_word have been guessed so far.
    '''
    ###alphabet='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    for l in letters_guessed:
        if l in alphabet:
            alphabet=alphabet.replace(l,'')
            print(alphabet)
    for l in alphabet:
        if l in secret_word:
            secret_word=secret_word.replace(l,'_ ')
            print(secret_word)
    return secret_word

print(get_guessed_word(secret_word, letters_guessed))
```

Thank you in advance for your help. I know this is a common error, but none of the articles I read addressed my specific issue.

Comment: It "was" defined, but you commented it out, so ... it's not. The error is correct. You should probably use a different name so you don't think it's the global alphabet.

Answer (score 0):

the answer for your question relays on the fact you're assigning alphabet in the get_guessed_work function.

when you're assigning an immutable variable (a string for example) inside a function, Python automatically treats this variable as local, and not global.
therefore, alphabet is now a global variable, which you did not define earlier on.
you can fix this problem by adding a default function variable to functions declaration:

```
def get_guessed_word(secret_word, letters_guessed,alphabet=alphabet):
```

hope that helped!
Maxim.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add

```
global alphabet
```

like

```
secret_word = 'apple'
letters_guessed = ['a','p','q']#['e', 'i', 'k', 'p', 'r', 's']
alphabet='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'


def is_word_guessed(secret_word, letters_guessed):
    '''
    secret_word: string, the word the user is guessing; assumes all letters are
      lowercase
    letters_guessed: list (of letters), which letters have been guessed so far;
      assumes that all letters are lowercase
    returns: boolean, True if all the letters of secret_word are in letters_guessed;
      False otherwise
    '''
    secret_letters=set()
    for l in secret_word:
        if l in alphabet:
            secret_letters.add(l)
            print('Secret letters are ',secret_letters)
        else:
            pass
    for l in letters_guessed:
        if l in secret_letters:
            secret_letters.remove(l)
            print('Secret letters minus guessed letters are', secret_letters)
        else:
            pass
    if len(secret_letters)==0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
        
print(is_word_guessed(secret_word, letters_guessed))

def get_guessed_word(secret_word, letters_guessed):
    '''
    secret_word: string, the word the user is guessing
    letters_guessed: list (of letters), which letters have been guessed so far
    returns: string, comprised of letters, underscores (_), and spaces that represent
      which letters in secret_word have been guessed so far.
    '''
    global alphabet
    for l in letters_guessed:
        if l in alphabet:
            alphabet=alphabet.replace(l,'')
            print(alphabet)
    for l in alphabet:
        if l in secret_word:
            secret_word=secret_word.replace(l,'_ ')
            print(secret_word)
    return secret_word

print(get_guessed_word(secret_word, letters_guessed))
```

Tip: avoid naming function arguments the same as variables because it gets confusing
and also you should always use

```
x = y
```

and not

```
x=y
```

just for aesthetic reasons.

```
secret_word = 'apple'
letters_guessed = ['a','p','q']
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'


def is_word_guessed(word, guess):
    '''
    secret_word: string, the word the user is guessing; assumes all letters are
      lowercase
    letters_guessed: list (of letters), which letters have been guessed so far;
      assumes that all letters are lowercase
    returns: boolean, True if all the letters of secret_word are in letters_guessed;
      False otherwise
    '''
    secret_letters = set()
    for l in word:
        if l in alphabet:
            secret_letters.add(l)
            print('Secret letters are ',secret_letters)
        else:
            pass
    for l in guess:
        if l in secret_letters:
            secret_letters.remove(l)
            print('Secret letters minus guessed letters are', secret_letters)
        else:
            pass
    if len(secret_letters) == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
        
print(is_word_guessed(secret_word, letters_guessed))

def get_guessed_word(word, guess):
    '''
    secret_word: string, the word the user is guessing
    letters_guessed: list (of letters), which letters have been guessed so far
    returns: string, comprised of letters, underscores (_), and spaces that represent
      which letters in secret_word have been guessed so far.
    '''
    global alphabet
    for l in guess:
        if l in alphabet:
            alphabet = alphabet.replace(l,'')
            print(alphabet)
    for l in alphabet:
        if l in word:
            word = word.replace(l,'_ ')
            print(word)
    return word

print(get_guessed_word(secret_word, letters_guessed))
```

Hope I helped.